# Copy array via memcpy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcpy

I saw there are a lot of articles about memcpy but I can't find the solution for my problem. Can somebody see why the copy action doesn't work?

```
float MeanFilter(const volatile float *Array, volatile float Dist){
float Avg = 0.0;    // Variable used to calculate the average distance value
float Sorted[MaxDistArray]; // Array used to contain the sorted array

printf("\n");
int j;

for(j = 0; j < 20; j++){
    if(j == 10) printf("\n \t");
    printf("%d: %f, ", j+1, Array[j]);
}

memcpy(Sorted, &Array[0], sizeof(float));
Sort(Sorted);   // Sort the array of distances values

printf("\n");

for(j = 0; j < 20; j++){
    if(j == 10) printf("\n \t");
    printf("%d: %f, ", j+1, Sorted[j]);
}
```

Comment: What *is* the problem you are having? Can you please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? And also tell us what input you give, and the expected and actual output from that input.

Comment: Oh and you probably should [read a `memcpy` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). Pay close attention to the last (the `count`) argument and what it is supposed to be.

Comment: You only copy a single value; If you multiply the `sizeof(float)` with the number of floats you'd like to copy, you might get better results.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idd @Ronald that was part of the solution

```
memcpy(Sorted, Array, sizeof(float)*MaxDistArray);
```

thx!